# How to diagnose fast battery discharge

Tags: batteries, lipo

How do you predict how long it will take a battery to discharge? I thought it was simply `t = C/I`, but I'm experiencing a very fast discharge rate.

I bought [this](https://www.hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-nano-tech-3000mah-2s2p-20-40c-lipo-receiver-pack.html) 3000mAh 7.4V lipo battery, and my multimeter says my circuit (containing a switching 5V regulator) draws a fairly constant 680mA. So I would have expected to get around `3/0.68` = 4.4 hours of run time. However, I'm finding my battery's voltage drops below the usable 5V mark in about 10 minutes, after which the battery is effectively dead.

What am I missing? Why is my battery discharging so quickly?

Edit: The only other thing I think could be a factor is that I've wired [this lipo protection board](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N48RCS8) between the battery and my circuit, to protect it from dropping to a voltage that would permanently damage the battery. My current measurements from the battery are after this board. I haven't measured the current leaving the battery before this board.

Comment: Your logic is sound. There is something wrong with the battery. Maybe it is not fully charged or has become imbalanced or is somehow defective. Are you charging it using a balance charger? Can you measure the voltage at both cells after you charge it?

Comment: Do you have two multimeters,.one for current and one for voltage? The current is not going to remain constant during battery discharge. In fact, with a linear regulator, it should be dropping. With a switch-mode regulator, it could be increasing.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, if the pack is good and is being discharged in 10 minutes, that is 6C. 18 Amps. More or less. I don't think such a large discrepancy can be explained by slight variation in current vs voltage. Either the load is drawing much more than 680 mA, or there is something wrong in the charging or something wrong with the battery pack. Would make sense to measure the load current throughout the discharge cycle, but I don't think it is essential to use two meters.

Comment: How do you charge the 2-cell battery? Are your charging each cell separately, or else?

Comment: @mkeith, Yes, I charge it with a balance charger. I haven't checked the voltage across the cells separately, but the battery fully charged was the expected 7.4V.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, I did measure both current and voltage, and the current remained relatively constant, but the voltage dropped quickly. All my regulators are high efficiency switching UBECs.

Comment: "but the battery fully charged was the expected 7.4V." I would have expected 8.4V. 7.4V indicates about half-charged.

Comment: It sounds like one cell is nearly dead, dried out.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, True. However, even at half charge, I'd still expect more than 10 minutes of runtime.

Comment: If one of the cells is only charged up to 3.2V then it may not last very long. it's almost at the edge of the discharge curve.

Comment: @AliChen, But wouldn't that mean one cell is nearly at 7V? Lipo cells start to puff and may explode if you charge them above 5V. My battery hasn't puffed at all.

Comment: @Cerin, no. It is likely that one of cells has developed abnormally high internal impedance. When a charger works, it will stop at 4.2V, but the cell will not get any significant charge. If you have 7.4V as "charged", one possible scenario is that one good cell has 4.2V, and the bad one is at 3.2V, or near total depletion.

Comment: Ah, protection circuit... then all bets are off. :-( Still, what do you measure on each of your cells?

Comment: If the pack cannot attain close to 8.4V when "fully charged" on a good charger then something is seriously wrong with the pack. It could be unbalance or a bad cell or both bad cells. You should have zero expectation about battery life until you have two good cells that are in balance. Balance chargers cannot necessarily fix a badly unbalanced pack immediately. But it is a bad sign for a pack to become badly unbalanced unless you rebuilt it yourself with cells at different charge state.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, You were correct. The storage charge of 3.7V/cell was not enough. I used a different charger to get it to 4.2V/cell, and the battery lasted 3.75 hours. Now I have to figure out why my charger is only getting it to 3.7V/cell.

Comment: @Cerin, why don't you write that up as an answer to your own question and accept it? It is OK to answer your own question.